# PHPunit can't find tests

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

PHPunit isn't able to find my tests, but it does find my XML configuration. This is the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Symply Test Suite">
            <directory>src/Symply/EventManager/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And this is the directory structure:

[image: directory structure]
PHPunit just says, when running the script, "No tests executed".
I don't know why this doesn't work, since I specified the directory in the XML directory tags.

Comment: Could you post the EventManagerTest.php file also?

Comment: Yes! Nothing special actually: http://pastebin.com/mtnhGD4D

Comment: I can't see any problems with the posted code, but I haven't used PHP namespaces so I can't speak for that. Have you tried setting the logging in php.ini to as much as possible and also display_errors to on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When just using PHPunit trough the commandline, everything just works fine. I guess there is some problem in Netbeans. I need to specify a test folder there, so I guess I will just choose the src folder? Thanks to all the people trying to help me.

Comment: you should have stated that this happens when you run phpunit from netbeans, not on CLI only.

Comment: yeah true, but it was also failing on CLI yesterday. Probably it fixed thanks to that suffix tip from you.

Comment: this whole thing is hilarious!

Answer (score 18):

You need to provide the `suffix` attribute:

```
<directory suffix="Test.php">...</directory>
```

Read [the documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this: http://pastebin.com/temJ08de But it still doesn't find the test. Strange...

Comment: can you run the file directly with phpunit? `$ phpunit path/to/fileTest.php`?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this same problem. This post is a little old but thought I would share what I figured out from reading this page and looking into it more.

The files in the test directory did not end with *Test.php
When I changed them to that format it worked.
That is awesome that you can define your own naming convention by defining the suffix in the xml.

Hope that helps anyone who might read this and still be a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to run my test on PhpStorm using PHPUnit 7.1.5 and php7.1.16, this gives me the No tests executed message. Change my PHPUnit to 4.8.36 and it works fine.